# When does the Solidity function return variables return during the tx lifecycle

Tags: solidity

I have a function which writes into the blockchain. I would like to know if the transaction which calls the function has been succcessful or not. So far I did this with the tx receipt, but that takes multiple seconds to get. I don't need the tx receipt for further processing, therefore I am wondering if it is possible to figure out (hopefully faster) if the tx was successful or not. My first idea is that it can be simply done with a return value from the function. So my question is that when will my web3 client receive the return value of the `fooFunction`? I assume when the block/tx was validated. Or can I get back the `currentBalance` return value from the function while the tx will fail? Or if my client gets the proper return value that means the tx has been executed properly?

```
function fooFunction (address addr, address rec) external return (uint256) {
    IBEP20 tokenContractObject = IBEP20(addr);
    uint256 currentBalance = tokenContractObject.balanceOf(address(this));
    // do some work with the balance
    return currentBalance
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> when will my web3 client receive the return value of the fooFunction?

If the transaction is successful. Also, not all functions that write to the blockchain require a return value.

> Or can I get back the currentBalance return value from the function while the tx will fail?

No, if the transaction fails, it will revert with an error message.

> Or if my client gets the proper return value that means the tx has been executed properly

Not necessarily, sometimes a transaction can go smoothly on the client side but an error occurs on the server side. I would say if a transaction goes smoothly on both the client and server side, it's considered been executed properly.